# calling function prototype in handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I built a simple app using express and handlebars

in my models, I have function prototype like this

```
// myModel.js
Student.prototype.getFullname = function () {
  return `${this.first_name} ${this.last_name}`;
}
```

in my router, I can invoke the function prototype like this

```
// myRouter.js
const rows = await Model.Student.findAll();
console.log(rows[0].getFullname()); // I can invoke function prototype here
res.render('mypage', rows); // with express, render it to hbs
```

my question: how to call a function prototype in handlebars?

```
{{#each this}}
<tr>
    <td>{{ id }}</td>
    <td>{{ first_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ last_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ rows[0].getFullname() }}</td> // I wanna call it here
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: why don't you make `full_name` a getter? `Object.defineProperty(Student.prototype, "full_name", {get(){ return this.first_name + " " + this.last_name }})` or `class Student { get full_name(){ return ... }}`

Comment: It is the requirement i got in my bootcamp. im doing task here

Comment: Then you could register a helper that helps you call that method.

Comment: i dont understand helper right now, can you give me some clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [handlebars helpers docs](http://handlebarsjs.com/#helpers), there's literally your example, with the `fullName` helper.

Registering helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('getFullName', function(student) {

    return `${student.first_name} ${student.last_name}`;

});
```

Using helper:

```
{{#each this}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ id }}</td>
      <td>{{ first_name }}</td>
      <td>{{ last_name }}</td>
      <td>{{ getFullName this }}</td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

A generic helper to run methods with arguments if needed?

helpers.js

```
 //{{run this.proto 'method' arg1, ...}}
Handlebars.registerHelper('run', function(proto, method)
{
    return proto[method].apply(null,Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2,-1));
});
```

handlebars code

```
      {{run rows[0] 'getFullName'}}
```